# Resposive Grid for Xamarin.Forms not resposive enough

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using a simple grid to make a menu list responsive for all resolutions. It's mainly working fine but if you see it on Android (and UWP if I resize the view to a small width) the right side has less space than the left size which has made it really ugly and unprofessional. Can you help me fix it?

This is the code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please, share a [mcve]

Comment: How does it look like when It's not working ?

Comment: @LeRoy what of shared is how it looks like. If you look closely the left side of the view has more white space than the right side.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms, Grid takes Padding by itself so you should set Padding Accordingly **OR** if you don't want Padding than set **Padding=0** .

Answer (score 0):

process of illumination ?:

Could you also change the background colour of your ContentPage to make sure its not applying the margin.

most likely you have something like `margin="2, 0, 0, 0"` somewhere in your code

```
    <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
        <Grid Padding="0" Margin="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```